# Did Richard Nixon say, "Jews think they can run the world"?

Tags: united-states, quotes, antisemitism

[Daily Stormer](http://www.dailystormer.com/nixon-and-the-jews/):

> In Chicago the demonstrators got close enough to rough up Pompidou and spit on his wife. “This is unconscionable,” raged Nixon. “**The fucking Jews think they can run the world.** Well…” And on and on.

While researching for the claim, I came across [this](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/politics/daily/oct99/nixon6.htm) Washingtonpost article that has other similar quotes by Nixon:

> "The Jews are all over the government," Nixon complained to his chief
>   of staff, H.R. "Bob" Haldeman, in an Oval Office meeting recorded on
>   one of a set of White House tapes released yesterday at the National
>   Archives. Nixon said the Jews needed to be brought under control by
>   putting someone "in charge who is not Jewish" in key agencies.
>
> Washington "is full of Jews," the president asserted. "Most Jews are
>   disloyal." He made exceptions for some of his top aides, such as
>   national security adviser Henry Kissinger, his White House counsel,
>   Leonard Garment, and one of his speechwriters, William Safire, and
>   then added:
>
> "But, Bob, generally speaking, you can't trust the bastards. They turn
>   on you. Am I wrong or right?"
>
> Haldeman agreed wholeheartedly. "Their whole orientation is against
>   you. In this administration, anyway. And they are smart. They have the
>   ability to do what they want to do--which is to hurt us."

Did Richard Nixon say, "Jews think they can run the world"?

Comment: Why do you keep repeating claims from the stormer?  You know they're Nazis, right?

Comment: @CPerkins There are several reasons. The first is that I want to understand this ideology. And some people think they can shut me up whenever I speak about certain topics by the abuse of power. **I don't like that.**

Comment: You can remove the Stormer link altogether, since the quote is taken from the book, as you have shown. I think the latter is much more notable than the former.

Comment: What's with the obsession with Jew questions?

Comment: What people are those?

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin where did the question about Jewish Center bomb threats go? http://www.cnn.com/2017/03/23/middleeast/israeli-american-teen-arrested-jcc-bomb-threats/index.html I can't find it any more.  Did moderators delete it?

Comment: @DavePhD http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37432/are-bomb-threats-against-jews-false-flag-attacks

Deleted by community for inactivity. I voted to reopen it.

Comment: @DavePhD And it seems he was trolling. His trolling skills are poor. He doesn't seem to know the limits of trolling. Stupid troll, now go to jail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quote is in the 2002 book [President Nixon: Alone in the White House](https://books.google.com/books?id=ajLBlZwwB0IC&pg=PA170&dq=%22Jews%20think%20they%20can%20run%20the%20world%22%20Haldeman&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl6_fssLbSAhUB7CYKHeRyB3kQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22Jews%20think%20they%20can%20run%20the%20world%22%20Haldeman&f=false) at page 170.

I can't tell if the book is quoting [H. R. Haldeman's diary](http://www.nytimes.com/1994/05/18/us/haldeman-diary-shows-nixon-was-wary-of-blacks-and-jews.html) or not.

Comment: Is this book reliable?

Comment: @MohammadSakibArifin my guess is it is based upon the 26 February 1970 diary entry of Hardeman.

Comment: Does anyone have access to a copy of  H. R. Haldeman's diary to confirm this?

Comment: @Tory This book specifically says the quote is from the diary https://books.google.com/books?id=TP4g-RhUJmcC&pg=PA66&dq=%22think+they+can+run+the+world%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd-4e9x7rSAhXDPCYKHXYvArwQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22think%20they%20can%20run%20the%20world%22&f=false but I haven't been able to directly verify.

Comment: @DavePhD Yep.  I'm just leery of blindly accepting a book's sourcing of a quote (e.g. most quotes involving Gandhi and Christianity).  In this case, the source isn't some vaguely specified interview, but rather an actual document that can be read and confirmed to have/not have said quote.

Comment: @Tory yes, I agree completely.  The Nixon library has the actual diaries https://www.nixonlibrary.gov/virtuallibrary/documents/haldeman-diaries/haldeman-diaries-1970.php#handwritten but the relevant ones aren't online.  And there is the book form https://books.google.com/books?id=M4wsgK5MxX8C&q=Haldeman+Diaries&dq=Haldeman+Diaries&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif3ono07rSAhVE6yYKHS4pDTcQ6AEIGjAA but I don't know how complete that is.  I can't find such a quoting using google-search in the book

Comment: I got a copy of *The Haldeman Diaries*.  The entry for 26 Feb 1970: "Really raged again today against United States Jews because of their behavior toward Pompidou.  Has decided to postpone Jewish arms supply for their 'unconscionable conduct'.  Also said, in front of [Kissinger], not to let any Jews see him about the Middle East.  Said they can go talk to Lindsay and Rockefeller about whether *they* can provide arms for Israel.  As made as he's been since we got here."  So "unconscionable" is a direct quote, but there's nothing like "run the world".

Comment: I checked the other entries for Pompidou in the index.  The next closest is 18 Feb 1970: "Really mad at the Jews because of Pompidou reaction and is saying so pretty loudly".